# Build SQL query with long hex strings in Python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, sqlite, hex

I have the array of md5 hashes as hex strings:

```
hashes = ['abcdefabcdefabcdef', '12f456789012345678', 'acd24ef6dcbe98753a']
```

I need to build a SQL query to find records by the hashes. If I create a query manually, it looks like this `"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE hash IN (x'abcdefabcdefabcdef', x'12f456789012345678', x'acd24ef6dcbe98753a')"`

For a single hash I'd use string formatting, like this `"SELECT * ... WHERE md5 = x'%s'" % hash`

However I have no idea how to build the query using array transformations in Python to put it into the sqlite3's `cursor.execute()` method.

Comment: Not clear for me, why can't you use cycle to go through the hashes? Like for every hash call cursor.execute([query with current hash]).

Comment: @Alex First, one execute() call seems more efficient rather than calling execute() in a loop. Second, it's not a problem to build the query using a loop, I'm just wondering if I can build the query with long hex strings using more elegant way in Python.

Comment: Ok, I still don't get the root problem. You described good approach using IN clause, why it will not work for you? To make this query you just need "select... in (x'" + str(hashes.join(',x')) + "');" - than execute. What kind of elegant tweaks you would like to have here?

Comment: @Alex Thank you. Actually I'm not a Python programmer, so the solution you described seems like the solution I'm looking for. With a small correction it will look like: "(x'" + str("', x'".join(hashes)) + "')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Alex comment:

```
“SELECT... IN (x'" + str("', x'".join(hashes)) + "');”
```